# Insert LocalStorage value into Form Input Field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am storing a value in localStorage.

I'm looking to insert this value into the input field value with Javascript. How do I do this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5apg1mh3/

```js
localStorage.setItem("email", "test");
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="email" name="email"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.getElementById('email').setAttribute('value', localStorage.getItem('email'));`